# How to create custom datepicker from json in Ionic 4/Angular?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm developing ionic 4 page with multi range datepicker which the calendar data source from json api.

JSON API:

```
 [
    {
        "day"       : "27-MAY-2019 00:00:00",
        "status"    : "HD"
    },
    {
        "day"       : "26-MAY-2019 00:00:00",
        "status"    : "WD"
    },
    {
        "day"       : "25-MAY-2019 00:00:00",
        "status"    : "WD"
    },
    {
        "day"       : "24-MAY-2019 00:00:00",
        "status"    : "HD"
    }
    ]
```

The data above showing status `WD` for Workday and `HD` for holiday. How can i create datepicker with multi range selection and disable/ignore the `HD` status from range selection?

[Datepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBAVW.png)

Thanks for help :)